# Sitecore User Permission gets over written on deployment and Unicorn Sync

Tags: sitecore-client, unicorn

I have set permissions to users on the Sitecore `security editor`

All those User permissions get over written on `Unicorn Sync` during deployments

[image]

I Understand that security is controlled at Item level , Is there a way to ignore  only the security field of all items during `Unicorn Sync` , so that they are not controlled by `yaml` file but through the `security editor` in Sitecore.

Please suggest the common practice solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a exclude field filter for these purposes.

Usage:

```
<configuration name="ExcludeConfig" description="Exclude configuration for excluding the Security field">                      
    <fieldFilter type="Rainbow.Filtering.ConfigurationFieldFilter, Rainbow" singleInstance="true">
        <exclude fieldID="{DEC8D2D5-E3CF-48B6-A653-8E69E2716641}" note="'Security' field on Standard Template" />
    </fieldFilter>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did it really work? I think fieldFilter is used only for Serializing the item (to Yaml), but not for Deserializing it (To Sitecore DB).
You may have to use fieldtransformations for this.